# Hibernate Mapping files path for gradle and eclipse

Tags: eclipse, hibernate, gradle

I am using `gradle` builds for our build process and need eclipse for our development environment. Gradle expects the `hibernate.cfg` and `.hbm` files in a folder `main/resources` inside of the `src` folder. But eclipse expects it directly inside of `src` folder.

```
Gradle
  - src
     - main
        - resources
          hibernate.cfg
          package/path/.hbm files

Eclipse
  - src
    hiberante.cfg
    package/path/.hbm files
```

To get it working on eclipse I have modified the .cfg file to have mappings with the folder prefixed. But when I do a gradle build, the below hack fails and I get a 'org.hibernate.boot.MappingNotFoundException: Mapping (RESOURCE) not found : main/resources/com/mnox/database/hibernate/pojos/v2/Booking.hbm.xml :`

```
<mapping resource="main/resources/com/mnox/database/
```

**EDIT 1**

I tried the following, did not work for gradle.
To fix the issues I did the folllowing

1. I moved all the .hbm files from `src/main/resources/package/path` to `src/package/path`.
2. I retained the `.cfg` file in `src/main/resources`
3. In the `.cfg` file I ensured that the path was `package/path/Booking.hbm.xml`

Both `Gradle` and `Eclipse` now work.

**EDIT 2**

```
apply plugin: 'java'
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.21'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
//compile files('src/com/mnox/database/hibernate/pojos/v2')
}
jar {
    baseName='databasepojos'
    from ('src/com/mnox/database/hibernate/pojos/v2/*.xml')
//    from ('build/classes/main')
}
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDir 'src'
                //includes = 'src/com/mnox/database/hibernate/pojos/v2/**'
                //includes = ["**/*.java"]
        }
    }
}
allprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'
    sourceCompatibility = 1.7
    targetCompatibility = 1.7
}
FileTree hbmfilesFrom = fileTree(dir: 'src/com/mnox/database/hibernate/pojos/v2/*.hbm.xml')
task copyHBMXMLFiles(type: Copy) {
    from hbmfilesFrom
    into 'build/main/resources/com/mnox/database/hibernate/pojos/v2'
}
```

**EDIT 3**

My .classpath file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="owner.project.facets" value="java"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="build"/>
</classpath>
```

Comment: Down voter, please explain. Its crazy to get a down vote for a good question.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your application and/or tests are referring to `hibernate.cfg` via the classpath all you need to do is make sure that `src/main/resources` is a classpath folder in both `gradle` and `eclipse`.

- In gradle that's simple as this is the default
- I'm not sure how you are generating your eclipse project but `src` should NOT be on the classpath. It should be `src/main/resources` plus the compiled classes directory.
- I advise against manually creating an eclipse project for your gradle project
- Do you know there's the [buildship eclipse plugin](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/tools.buildship)?
- Alternatively, do you know that you can generate `.classpath` and `.project` using the [gradle plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/eclipse_plugin.html#sec:eclipse_tasks)?

Comment: In eclipse, I remove "src" form Java Build Path and added src/main/resource. All hell broke loose. I need to exactly what I need to change in "eclipse" to get this working. I understand the fundamentals, but where do I make the change in eclipse so that hibernate files are picked up from "src/main/resources" and not "src" folder.

Comment: The buildshipplugin does not work on "dependent projects" (how lame)

Comment: Add `apply plugin: 'eclipse'` to your `build.gradle` then run `gradle eclipse` from command line. Note that this will overwrite your `.project` and `.classpath`

Comment: You can define a [Composite Build](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/composite_builds.html) if you want inter project dependencies in buildship